# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'admin' but everything seems correct

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am getting this error message in Java while trying to connect to a SQL Server database:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'admin'. ClientConnectionId:81b24c93-1297-4713-91c8-7f639b172de3
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at first.assign_Code.createConn(assign_Code.java:34)
    at first.assign_Code.getQueryResultInMap(assign_Code.java:42)
    at first.assign_Code.main(assign_Code.java:73)
```

It is strange because it can establish connection, but fails trying to login.

This is my code:

```
 package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;

public class assign_Code {
    static Connection conn = null;
    static QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
    static boolean keepConnection = false;
    
    public static void createConn(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password) throws SQLException, IOException {

        if (conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
            String driver = null;
            DbUtils.loadDriver(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, usernameString, driverr);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
    }
    
    public static Map<String, Object> getQueryResultInMap(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password,String sqlQuery, Object... params) throws SQLException, IOException {

        try {
            createConn(urlString,driverr,usernameString,password);
            if (params == null) {
                return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapHandler());
            } else {
                return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapHandler(), params);
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            closeConn();
        }
    }
    
    public static void closeConn() throws SQLException {
        if (!keepConnection) {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SQLException, IOException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\SELENIUM\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    String urlString="jdbc:sqlserver://dfd45.hhgt.local:1433;databaseName=Test";
    String usernameString="admin";
    String password="admin";
    String driverr="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String sqlQuery= "select sku from fuse.orders.WebOrderItem where itemid = ?";
    
    
    Map<String,Object>resultSet= getQueryResultInMap(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "3");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    }

}
```

Take a look at this:

```
    String urlString="jdbc:sqlserver://dfd45.hhgt.local:1433;databaseName=Test";
    String usernameString="admin";
    String password="admin";
    String driverr="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I can connect to the SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio, but it fails to connect in Java:

[image]

What's wrong here? Is anything wrong?

Comment: "Login failed" doesn't necessarily mean "Incorrect username or password," though that's often the case. When specifying the `databaseName` parameter in your JDBC connection string the target database has to exist already and your SQL Login must have previously been granted access to it. Does the `Test` database already exist? Has the `admin` login been mapped to a database user with sufficient access in it? Given the select query perhaps you need to specify the `fuse` database instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not include the password in the statement:

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, usernameString, driverr);`

It should be:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, usernameString, password);
```

Comment: It should be `DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, usernameString, password)`, the `driverr` doesn't belong in the request for a connection.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I see:

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, usernameString, driverr);`

This string is wrong.

```
This method describes:
public static Connection getConnection(String url,
        String user, String password) throws SQLException
```

At the 3rd place must be the password.